# Delete a project in a site

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone know how to delete a project(script) in a site?

I made a new script and copied a code from another project to change the owner of the script, but cannot delete a project which I don't use any more. There isn't delete in file menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your site, go to 'manage site, open the script project you want to delete[image]

In the **file menu within the script** choose 'delete'

[image]

Comment: It seems that there isn't delete in file menu because the owner of the script haven't changed. I can delete it when I logon as the account which I made the script,